# How to define random effects in the linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r

I read a paper which applied linear mixed-effects model for data analysis. I am confused about defining random effects in the equations.

First, how to define a combined random effect, such as − where  indicates plot number and  indicates somewhat classification results.
Second, how to include random effects in the slope term, such as intercept + slope * (var1 + random effect) + residuals

I do not know how to write code to represent this equations.

I expect an expression of these equations.

Comment: what R libraries are you using? The [lme4 FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) is a great resource for this type of question.

Comment: voting to close as off-topic/migrate to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). It could be legitimately be construed as a programming question, but there are already [lots of similar questions on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lme4+formula) ...

Answer (score 0):

Like Nate mentioned, the lme4 package will do all that you'd need. Their vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) will have the examples for your answer, particularly section 2.2.

Simple REs can be written using `(1 | group)` which will add a `group`-specific intercept estimated, and a random effect on the intercept varying by `group` for the fixed effect `x` let's say, can be written as `(1 + x | group)`.